# In PyTorch/Numpy, how to multiply rows of a matrix with "matrices" in a 3-D tensor?

Tags: numpy, pytorch

For example, `a = torch.Tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])` (for numpy it is just `a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`), and `b = torch.ones((2,2,2))`,

I would like to product every row of `a` with the two `2x2` matrices, and get a new matrix `[[3,3],[7,7]]` (i.e. `[1,2]*[[1,1],[1,1]]=[3,3]`, `[3,4]*[[1,1],[1,1]]=[7,7]`). Is it possible to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this an ugly solution, but perhaps this is what you want to achieve:

```
a = torch.Tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = torch.ones((2,2,2))

A = torch.mm(a[0].view(-1, 2), b[0])
B = torch.mm(a[1].view(-1, 2), b[1])
res = torch.cat([A, B], dim=0)
print(res)
```

**output:**

```
tensor([[3., 3.],
        [7., 7.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use regular matrix multiplication `a @ b`:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.ones((2,2,2))

print(a @ b)
```

Output:

```
[[[3. 3.]
  [7. 7.]]

 [[3. 3.]
  [7. 7.]]]
```

Each "row" of the result (ie the first index) will be a separate 2 x 2 matrix:

```
print((a @ b)[1])
```

Output:

```
[[3. 3.]
 [7. 7.]]
```